Tailwind CSS: Headings with text-size set for different breakpoints ignore leading without explicitly setting it
See: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DLVKgZRNxl
(widen the window to see the xl breakpoint)
Seems that if you specify different text sizes for different breakpoints, TW requires that you also specify respective leading explicitly. I.e. If I set a default text size of text-3xl leading-tight sm:leading-loose, then specify sm:text-4xl xl:text-5xl for the same element, it [incorrectly?] uses the default leading (3xl) unless I also specify xl:leading-loose.
As I understand it, styling by breakpoint implies that, unless anything is specified at a larger breakpoint, it will maintain a setting for that breakpoint and above unless instructed otherwise. So at xl, it should be defaulting to sm:leading-loose, correct?
(Hard-coding line-height in the element also doesn't appear to affect it.)

Thats because the light height which is applied by the sm:leading-loose will be overriden by the line height in the xl:text-5xl.
css for xl:text-5xl
    .xl\:text-5xl {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 1;
    }
}


Interesting...strikes me as too verbose—and not consistent with TW's schema. If sm:text-xl implies xl-sized text at all breakpoints including and above sm, then why not leading?

because the line height applied at sm will be overridden by the line heigth in xl in the text-5xl. This is the default behaviour of CSS. TW has to tweak some changes i guess to make it better

Definitely creates more verboseness this way.
